# Pick's Theorem for plane triangles in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

Pick's theorem asserts that, given a simple lattice polygon $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, if $I$ is the number of lattices inside $p$ and $B$ is the number of lattices on the boundary of $p$, then the area of $p$ equals $I + B/2 - 1.$ For example, if $p$ is the right triangle determined by the lattices $(0, 0)$, $(0, 1)$, and $(1, 0)$ then we have $I = 0$ and $B = 3$ so that the area $1/2$ of $p$ equals $I + B/2 - 1.$

Since it seems in principle that we can apply this theorem to a plane triangle $q$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, I am wondering then how we can obtain $I$ and $B$ for $q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you can have a triangle $(a,b, 0), (c,d,0), ( e,f,1)$ as big as you like that contains no lattice points except the vertices.

If there were a three-dimensional analogue (there isn't) it would be about tetrahedra, not triangles.